# Failing to import SQL

Tags: mysql

I'm migrating a website. When I attempt to import an SQL script, it does not work. I get the following error:

```
Error
consulta SQL:

--
-- Table structure for table `Log`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  `Log` ;

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1046 - No database selected
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you import your database structure using SQL script (MySQL)?

Answer (score 0):

You need the following towards the top of your script before any table references:

```
USE database_name_here;
```

From what you described this should help.